# Jquery cloned objects from multiple locations appending into same container

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I have two tables on a page which are being used in terrible ways for layout purposes. I need to move the contents of those tables into two containers, one for each table. I'm dealing with the following html.

```
<p>Paragraph of some stuff.</p>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Image</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>Paragraph with more stuff</p>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><em>Some fancy text</em></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't unwrap the existing tables. I have to modify cloned material. So I create some new containers before each table where I want to shove the stuff from the table using jquery and unwrap it, then wrap into some more legit elements.

Problem is I can't figure out to append all the cloned elements into their own special container just previous to the offending table. I use this jquery:

```
$('table').each(function () {
  $(this).before('<div class="ae-replaceTable"></div>');
  $('td').each( function() {
    $('.ae-replaceTable').append($(this).clone());
  });
});

$('.ae-replaceTable img').wrap('<p></p>');
$('.ae-replaceTable td').children().unwrap();
```

But what I end up with is everything from both tables in both containers. I need them to remain separate in the container created for them just above the specific table it comes from. So everything from table 1 ends up in div 1 and everything from table 2 ends up in div 2. Like so.

```
<p>Paragraph of some stuff.</p>

<div class="ae-replaceTable">
  <p>Image</p>
  <p>Image</p>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Image 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Image 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>Paragraph with more stuff</p>

<div class="ae-replaceTable">
  <p>Image 3</p>
  <p>Some fancy text.</p>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Image 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Some fancy text.</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit for clarification: I have this problem all over the site I'm working with so I can't go through each page and make unique classes for each table container. I need to be able to use one class name to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was just thinking about it the wrong way. Here is my new jquery:

```
$('table').before('<div class="ae-replaceTable"></div>');
$('table').each(function(){
  $(this).clone().insertBefore(this);
});

$('.ae-replaceTable').each(function() {
  $(this).append($(this).next('table'));
});

$('.ae-replaceTable img').wrap('<p></p>');
$('.ae-replaceTable td').children().unwrap();
$('.ae-replaceTable tr').children().unwrap();
$('.ae-replaceTable tbody').children().unwrap();
$('.ae-replaceTable table').children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very rudimentary, but we can spiff it up if you wish.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uSrYs/3/)

JS

```
$('#copy').on('click', function(){
   $(".upper tr td:eq(0)").clone().appendTo('.toptable');
   $(".upper tr td:eq(1)").clone().appendTo('.toptable');
   $(".lower tr td:eq(0)").clone().appendTo('.bottomtable');
   $(".lower tr td:eq(1)").clone().appendTo('.bottomtable');

   $('.toptable').css('display', 'block');
   $('.bottomtable').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Wish I could do that, but I have this problem all over the site I'm working with so I can't go through each page and make unique classes for each table container. Sorry, I should have specified that earlier.